# Pass bash file list to python CLI function

Tags: python, bash, argparse

I am using python's `argparse` to create command line bindings for popular functions from my software. More specifically I am talking about [this function](https://github.com/TheChymera/organamer/blob/c97a33b49c0aa01250a975d821784c8a50dc080b/src/organamer/cli.py#L7).

Usually when I want a CLI function to take a list of inputs in bash, I can do something like:

```
whateverfunction DSC_4{322..399}*
```

which will pass the function all values from `DSC_4322` to `DSC_4399` with whatever suffixes. Now, obvioulsy, this will not work if I am just passing a sting with `argparse` meaning to crawl the path in python:

```
parser.add_argument("destination", help="Path to store files into (excluding alphanumeric storage directories)", type=str)
```

Is there any elegant way to allow an `argparse` positional argument to handle bot a path and a list of files?

The only thing I could think of is detecting the accolades in the string and writing a python script which generates a list for such an input - and  performs a tree crawl for any other kind of input... But I was hoping there might be a nicer way.

Comment: Are you looking for `nargs='+'`?

Comment: `nargs='+'` is the right way to go if you want the shell to expand the file names for you. If you want python to do the expansion, you would need to put the spec in quotes (`whateverfunction "DCS_4{322..399}*`) so the shell passes the spec down.

Comment: `argparse` handles what you give it in the `sys.argv` list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with a simple script that echos the `sys.argv`

```
1959:~/mypy$ python echoargv.py stack{342..344}*
['echoargv.py', 'stack34234965.py', 'stack34279750.py', 'stack34308904.py', 'stack34432056.py']
```

I get a list of filenames

```
parser.add_argument("filenames", nargs='*')
```

will produce an `args` namespace like:

```
Namepace(filenames=['echoargv.py', 'stack34234965.py', 'stack34279750.py', 'stack34308904.py', 'stack34432056.py'])
```

Where there's no match I get a list like

```
python echoargv.py stack{23..24}*
['echoargv.py', 'stack23*', 'stack24*']
```

If you want generate a list of files from within the Python script, consider using `glob.glob`.

```
In [137]: glob.glob('stack342*')
Out[137]: ['stack34234965.py', 'stack34279750.py']
```

(though it does not, apparently, implement the `{..}` syntax.)

Comment: Ok, this sounds nice - would it work as the last positional argument? or would it also catch the keyword arguments that follow it? Would it catch the positional argument that preceeds it?

Comment: This `nargs` is greedy, so preventing it from catching all arguments AFTER it is a problem.  A fixed length positional before shouldn't be a problem.